# BigQuery Left Join on Revenue Data

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a LEFT join in BQ where I'm trying to join in some product classifications to the transactions data, but the revenue figures I end up with are much higher than the actual output. Can anybody see any glaring mistake I've made?

```
`with transactions as (
select
transaction_date,
retail_unit_code,
order_no,
line_type_code,
item_no,
item_type,
delivery_method,
customer_type,
sales_channel,
created_gross_quantity as created_gross_quantity,
created_sales_gross_amount_euro as created_sales_gross_amount_euro
from `sales.dataset`
),
item_data as (
select
item_no,
item_name,
item_type,
item_classification_1,
item_classification_2,
item_classification_3
from `item.classification.lookup`
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6)
select
t.transaction_date,
t.retail_unit_code,
t.order_no,
t.line_type_code,
t.item_no,
t.item_type,
t.delivery_method,
t.customer_type,
t.sales_channel,
(t.created_gross_quantity) as gross_quantity,
(t.created_sales_gross_amount_euro) as gross_revenue_euro,
id.item_name,
id.item_classification_1,
id.item_classification_2,
id.item_classification_3,
from transactions t
left join item_data id
on t.item_no = id.item_no and t.item_type = id.item_type`
```

I've tried setting SUM for the metrics as well, but that, funnily enough, doesn't make any difference...

Comment: Can you clarify what metric are you try to calculate? The `gross_quantity` and `gross_revenue_euro`? What breakdown you are looking for? per `item_no`? per `item_no` per `transaction_date`? per `item_type`?. I think you want to group by some dimension in your outer query when you use `SUM(created_sales_gross_amount_euro)`.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I'm trying to get a final breakdown by:
- item_no
- transaction date
- item_classification_1
- item_classification_2
- item_classification_3

And then sum the metric gross_revenue_euro